# $(this).val('') não retira informações do cache

Tags: html, jquery

A ideia é de que eu digite e se o valor for maior que a quantidade especificada então ele deixa o formulário em branco, até está tudo ok, porém, ao dar um alert o valor continua armazenado... O que pode ser?

```js
var quantidade = 100;
$('input').keyup(()=>{
            if ($('input').val() > quantidade && $('input').val().length == quantidade.length || $('input').val().length > quantidade.length)
            {
              $('input').val('');
            }});
            
$('button').click(()=>{ alert($('input').val()) })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="number" />
<button>Clicar</button>
```

Comment: Vc fez uma pergunta esses dias com esse mesmo código e eu volto a repetir, sua condição no `if` está errada, não existe propriedade **length** para tipo **`number`**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

é a sua validação que esta errada, tente assim:

```js
var quantidade = 100;
$('input').keyup(()=>{
            if ($('input').val() > quantidade && $('input').val().length > 0)
            {
              $('input').val('');
            }});
            
$('button').click(()=>{ alert($('input').val()) })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="number" />
<button>Clicar</button>
```